# why using messaging queue in web applications

Tags: django, httprequest, message-queue

When developing my web application using Django, I faced a problem, when I call some functions locally they work correctly, but once i call them over HTTP request they are not executed.
I asked around and i was told to execute them asynchronously outside the request response cycle using celery and a messaging queue server, it worked well, but still I don't understand why i have to execute some tasks asynchronously even when i don't have race condition and there's only one client calling the web service.
This is a big black spot for me because I make it work without really knowing how.
Can anyone explain it to me?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show some code and your problem?

Comment: def comp(request):
   p = subprocess.Popen(['javac',filepath],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=100)
      res, err =p.communicate()

   return HttpResponse (err)                                                                 when i call this application over http it didn't work until i used celery and defined a task where i execute the compilation outside the request/response cycle

Comment: does it work when using the dev server?

Answer (score 1):

The two main benefits I know of for queue-based systems are:

One, a response can be given to the client without having to wait for work to be done.  This lets pages load faster and clients spend less time waiting.

Second, a queue gives you a central location for scheduled jobs that multiple workers can draw from.  If a certain component of your application can't keep up with the amount of work there is to do (or if it fails for some reason), you can have other instances of that component doing the work, and there is a single place where all of the work that needs to be done can be found.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but the function i'm calling is to compile a .java file where a simple hello world is written, I don't think it's a big amount of work, and there is no reason for it to fail but when call it locally it works, when it's in a request/response cycle it doesn't

Comment: @JPR is answering the question you asked. If the answer you really want is to the question "Why won't this function work over HTTP but will work when called from celery" then you need to make that your question.